# Fluent NHibernate: Order by in left join with conditions

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, left-join

Suppose the following mapped classes:

```
public class Item
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual IEnumerable<History> Histories { get; set; }
}

public class History
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
  public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
  public virtual HistoryType HistoryType { get; set; }
}

public enum HistoryType
{
  A = 1,
  B = 2
}
```

Now I want to be able to fetch all items ordered by their latest History Date, where History is of HistoryType = A. Not all items have history so I guess a left join is needed.

What I need is a query for Fluent NHibernate but it would also be nice to see a correct SQL query for this.

Answer (score 1):

Standard SQL Query for your case will look like this. Yes you need a `Left Join` to get all items.

> all items ordered by their latest History Date, where History is of HistoryType = A. even for items that has not hisotry

```
SELECT i.id, h.id, h.datetime, h.historytype
FROM ITEMS i
LEFT JOIN HISTORY h
ON i.id = h.itemid
WHERE h.HistoryType = 'A'
ORDER BY h.Datetime DESC
```

If you choose to show a user-defined value istead of null. E.g. when an item has no history, history table reocrds returned will be null. Thus a function like [`Colasce`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) could help you to [add syntatic sugar to your query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) :)

Please apply the correct syntax (e.g. whether to use backtics/inverted commas for String/varchar columns values) for `Fluent NHibernate`.